# Fragment Lifecycle - onCreateView-UI elements

Tags: android, fragment

How we can access UI elements of a fragment in oncreateview, as onCreateView is called before onActivity created?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be inflating your UI elements within `onCreateView`, so they should be accessible there.  As long as you're only accessing UI elements within your `Fragment`, it's safe to inflate and use them at that point - you don't need to wait for `onActivityCreated` or anything like that.

Comment: Ohh, so in oncreateView, even if we are referencing to UI objects, they need not be initialised right? As these objects have activity as their reference?

Comment: Your `Context` (generally the `Activity`) exists and is guaranteed to be in the correct state of its lifecycle to be used to initialize UI objects when `onCreateView` is called.    The fact that `onActivityCreated` has not been called does not mean that there is not an `Activity` created, despite the name.  See [here](https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle) for more details on the lifecycles.

Comment: Thanks....The name "onActivityCreated" is kind of misleading, atleast for me :)